# remove parent padding for child div

Tags: html, css

I have a div#B in the div#A in HTML. div#A has padding in the CSS file and I want to doesn't affect on the div#B; I tried this ↓ but because of percent format they have, it doesn't work (doesn't fit completely to parent div because of the percent)!

```css
div#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: blue;
}
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#A {
  padding: 0.5% 2%;
  width: 76%;
  background: red;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#B {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 116px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: aqua;">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">this is sidebar and there is something here i dont know for now :))</div>
  <div id="A">
    <div id="B">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]

Comment: Plaes add also your HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine, made few minor updates to your css, have a look at the below-working snippet :)

```css
#A {
  padding: 1%;
  background: red;
}
#B {
  margin: -1%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

based on updated requirements, in your project can u update the `position` and `height` of the `#A`, if yes then below snippet will work for you

```css
div#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: blue;
}

#A {
  padding: 0.5% 2%;
  width: 76%;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 116px;
}

#B {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="A">
    <div id="B">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually the div#A is in the div#wrapper and div#A's width is 76% with 2% padding.

Comment: @Mehdi, please have a look at the second working snippet

Comment: i am glad it helped you, please upvote and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you add padding on your B, it will be solve your problem.

```
#B{
padding: 20%;}
```

Like that example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#B {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

The idea here is to push the container to the exact middle of the browser window with `left: 50%;`, then pull it back to the left edge with a negative margin `margin-left: -50vw;`.